# Maven: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile

Tags: java, maven, plugins, build

When I try to build my project using `mvn clean compile assembly:single docker:build` i get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project sd2122-tp1: Compilation failure
> [ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred

When I try to run it again but using  `mvn clean compile assembly:single docker:build -X` i get the following:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.153 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-20T14:24:16+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project sd2122-tp1: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project sd2122-tp1: Comp
ilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

```
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sd2122</groupId>
    <artifactId>sd2122-tp1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <authors>57369-57482</authors>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <dependencyConvergence />
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.39.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-dockerimage</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>sd2122-tp1-${authors}</name>
                            <build>
                                <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.15</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-ri</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
                <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
                <version>20050927</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Java and Maven version:

````
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.5
Java version: 17.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2
Default locale: pt_PT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"```

The full log output is here: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/hepisinape.bash
````

Comment: Please give the pom file, JDK version you are using, Maven version you are using etc. also full log output ...

Comment: I have updated the post with the information.

Comment: is there a good reason why you use `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` ? Keep the defaults... Also check first to run via `mvn clean` and a separate call `mvn test`...also located your production code into `src/main/java/<package>` and your test code in `src/test/java/<package>`...

Comment: Also please check why you need that dependency `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal` ??? Really with JDK 17... ?

Answer (score 2):

If the error message contains "lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor", include below dependency in pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.24</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error recently and I fixed it by doing the following.

Note that I use IntelliJ IDE.

1. Click on the `File` tab, and then click on Project Structure.
2. Then click on `Project` on the left pane. Under `Project SDK`, change it to the current Java Version in your project
3. Finally Click on `SDKs` and change the Java version to the current one in your project.

I hope this helps someone.